# Отвалился apt, aptitude и прочее подобное Debian

Tags: debian, apt

В очередной раз, при установке какого-то пакета, пытаясь порешать проблемы с зависимостями, я все таки ввел "Да, делать как я скажу!", не смотря на то, что оно обещало ушатать мою систему.

После чего - система вроде работает нормально но при попытке поставить какой-то новый покет - вываливает:

```
/usr/bin/apt: 1: /usr/bin/apt: ,: not found
/usr/bin/apt: 1: /usr/bin/apt: ,: not found
/usr/bin/apt: 2: /usr/bin/apt: ��
                                      -�#n������pj���: not found
/usr/bin/apt: 1: /usr/bin/apt: ELF: not found
/usr/bin/apt: 3: /usr/bin/apt: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Как можно это поправить?

Comment: Ну вот вы и ушатали систему, переустанавливайте с нуля.

Comment: @andreymal это слишком простой и очевидный путь для меня. Я так не люблю

Comment: программа *dpkg* работает? скачайте и установите пакет *apt* для вашей [версии дистрибутива и вашей архитектуры](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=apt&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all).

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin помогло. Спасибо